# Can we Clone XLWorkbook Object(Using ClosedXml)

Tags: closedxml

I'm using ClosedXml and Vb.net. I want to create clone XLWorkbook from existed XLWorkbook. But I have no idea. Can someone help me?
Is there anything like bellow?

```
Dim original As XLWorkbook
Dim clone AS XLWorkbook
original = New XLWorkbook("filepath")
clone = original.Clone()
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no `Clone()` method in ClosedXML. You have to save the Workbook (to a stream or file) and create a new Workbook from that copy.

Comment: That's correct. Cloning the input source would be must faster anyway.